# How to create new record and association in one row in Sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models in association: `Tournament` have many `Players`.
I am trying to achieve this:

```
const tournament = await db.Tournament.create(data);
const player  = await db.Player.create(data2);
await tournament.setPlayer(player);
```

But I am trying to achieve this in fewer rows. What I mean by that: I want to create a tournament and then somehow by some for example `addPlayer(data2)` add new row so I don't need to persist player first and THEN make the association.

Is this possible? Or I just need to persist `Tournament`, then persist `Player` and then glue them? What about if Player's column `tournament_id` cannot be null? Then code on top will not work too...

Any Suggestion?

Comment: If player is a direct association with tournament, why can't you pre-populate that relationship ID value on creation?

Comment: " I am trying to achieve this in fewer rows" - this is a bad goal - don't go that way...

Comment: Why? Less code = less query requests

Answer (score 0):

Older question, but I think this is the answer you're looking for: [Creating with Associations](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/creating-with-associations/)

```
return Product.create({
  title: 'Chair',
  user: {
    firstName: 'Mick',
    lastName: 'Broadstone',
    addresses: [{
      type: 'home',
      line1: '100 Main St.',
      city: 'Austin',
      state: 'TX',
      zip: '78704'
    }]
  }
}, {
  include: [{
    association: Product.User,
    include: [ User.Addresses ]
  }]
});
```

> Observe the usage of the include option in the `Product.create` call. That is necessary for Sequelize to understand what you are trying to create along with the association.